# how to use PrettyFaces in JSF projet with glassfish as server?

Tags: jsf

i tryed to use PrettyFaces with my jsf project but i had a error while deploying my projet.
thats what i have done :
i added this to my web.xml :

```
    <filter>
   <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping> 
       <filter-name>Pretty Filter</filter-name> 
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
       <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher> 
       <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher> 
       <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

and i created in web inf pretty-config.wml :

```
<pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/3.3.0" 
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/3.3.0
                                        http://ocpsoft.com/xml/ns/prettyfaces/ocpsoft-pretty-faces-3.3.0.xsd">

      <url-mapping> 
          <pattern value="/" /> 
          <view-id value="/faces/*" />
      </url-mapping> 

</pretty-config>
```

i added the jar of Prettyfaces to libs

> prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.0-sources

.

but when i deploy my projet i get this errors :

```
deploy?DEFAULT=C:\Users\hp\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PlanificationDrapage\dist\gfdeploy\PlanificationDrapage&name=PlanificationDrapage&force=true failed on GlassFish Server 3+ 
 Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.PrettyConfigListener. Please see server.log for more details.
C:\Users\hp\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PlanificationDrapage\nbproject\build-impl.xml:294: The module has not been deployed.
```

i am using netbeans with glassfish.
**Update :**
i resolved the first problem it was caused by using bad jar .

no i have Prettyfaces integrated and working when the Pretty-config.xhtml is empty but wheni add this code when i run my projet i have no errors but i white page.

thats what i add :

```
<url-mapping id="accueil"> 
    <pattern value="/" /> 
       <view-id value="/admin/adminHome.xhtml" />             
    </url-mapping>
```

how can i solve this problem ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are including `prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.0-sources` (the sources of Prettyfaces)  you have to include the binary jar.  From here for example:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ocpsoft
Or from here
http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ocpsoft/prettyfaces-jsf2/3.3.0/

Comment: i used your jar but still i have error Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : 
  Cause: Class 'com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.event.PrettyPhaseListener' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory. Please see server.log for more details.

Comment: as the error states, you need `LogFactory` in your classpath. Add the `commons-logging` jar to classpath.

Comment: it resolved the last erros but i have new error when running the project Grave: WebModule[/PlanificationDrapageWeb]PWC1270: Exception starting filter Pretty Filter
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/beanutils/Converter
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.beanutils.Converter
Avertissement: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
Avertissement: ApplicationDispatcher[/PlanificationDrapageWeb] PWC1231:

Comment: According to this link http://code.google.com/p/prettyfaces/issues/detail?id=26 I think you have some problem with your classpath. Please try to "Package prettyfaces jar in EAR, not WAR, for EAR deployments."

Comment: i fixed the problem i was just adding 2 jar that do same rule now i am using all what you said in the last post and its working when the pretty-config.xml have no code but when i add <url-mapping id="accueil"> 
    <pattern value="/" /> 
       <view-id value="/admin/adminHome.xhtml" />             
    </url-mapping> to my code whe i run my project i have a white page i see nothing do you know why ?

Comment: what URL do you call, and make sure there is no error in xhtml page

Comment: i didnt call it with pattern:accueil yet just added the code that i showed you and i get white page do you know why ?

Comment: there may be many causes, one of them is when you are writing code outside composition balise. So it's hard to say without code snippets. This very same example is working for me under tomcat

Comment: i tryed a test and i understant whats going when i add the code that i show you when the application run it consider it like default page and go to this page directly idk why

Comment: thank you for your help the problem was that i used wrong url i need to use with faces        <view-id value="/faces/admin/gestiondesarticles/afficherarticlehome.xhtml" />

Comment: i have in some bean to change page used with return i used return "pretty:afficherarticleges.xhtml"; but didnt work theres an other syntaxe ?

Comment: as I told you, in my other answer, you use `pretty:theIdYouGaveToYourMapping` in your petty-config ex: `pretty:accueil`

Comment: yes its working when i am using OUTCOME but now i want to change the page from managed bean and i tryed this same syntaxe but didnt work i made new topic for this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237480/how-to-change-jsf-page-from-managed-bean-using-prettyfaces